# Laravel : Removing an element from a collection array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

i use a variable called $users to "pluck" only the emails from my users table, using:

`$users = user::all()->pluck('email');`

when i dd($users), i get this

```
<pre>
Collection {#214 ▼
  #items: array:8 [▼
    0 => "adminone@example.com"
    1 => "admintwo@example.com"
    2 => "Adobot@example.com"
    3 => "Lawly@example.com"
    4 => "Cerms@example.com"
    5 => "Charlie@example.com"
    6 => "test@example.com"
    7 => "test001@example.com"
  ]
}
</pre>
```

meaning that $users isn't purely an array, i get various types of errors when i treat it like an array.

my question is, in php (in a Laravel Framework) how do i remove a specific user's email from the variable above? or is there a better way to use "pluck" so that it returns an array instead?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too and i solved it like this:

`DB::table('user')->pluck('email')->all();`

Comment: This was the solution i was looking for, as the above code returns an array instead of an Std Class Object, approved!

Answer (score 0):

Here `$users` is an Std Class Object, you can iterate over it and push its properties to an array like:

```
$userDetails = array();
foreach($users as $user)
{
  $userDetails[] = (array)$user;
  // or
  $userDetails[] = $user->index;
}
```

You can also put an `If` block inside `foreach()` to check some condition.

Comment: if i understand correctly, we're using foreach() to access the array inside (loops once) the Std Class Object, and then just move the whole array to $userDetails?
thanks for the speedy reply!

Comment: Kevin: foreach() is required to iterate over all properties of Std Class object. After iteration if you want the data in an array, then push it in an array variable, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to remove email where email id where index is 0  then you follow below query first**

```
   $users = user::all()->pluck('email');
   unset($users['0']);
   $dd($users);
```

Comment: i don't want to permanently remove the email from my database, just remove "Lawly@example.com" from $users variable.

Comment: similarly you remove other index from collections

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use `->forget()`

```
$collection->forget($key);
```

Or you can use [reject](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_reject) method

```
$newColection = $collection->reject(function($element) {
    return $element === 'emailaddress@';
});
```